# Is there any menu generator for Android apps?

Tags: android, menu, generator, android-menu

I feel that the coding of typical menus is quite boring and time consuming.
Given that most of the work to do there is mechanical I was wondering if there was any menu scaffold generator out there, I use eclipse and I feel that it does not ease this work too much.

What I'm looking for is quite simple, a plain and simple generator for a typical menu, preferences menu... not to much, the XML, the basic code and no more.

A full fledged app generator would do the trick, but what I have found so far are crude web-to-app generators.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://www.menucool.com/drop-down-menu) may help you. It is compatible with mobile devices also.

You can download the basic version or you can download it from torrent.